# How can I create a button before a control in another parent?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am having a XAML issue and I am sure it's because of the fact that order matters in XAML.

The question is, how can I create the button after the control with the `Selected` event on it if the button is in another parent? Because XAML order matters, and the `Selected` event has in its C# method a button which is made AFTER the control with the `Selected` event, and so when the application starts, the button is `null`, I get this this exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

SettingsStartupUpdateCheckBtn was null.
```

In XAML I have this code to make the button starting from line 782,:

```
<Button x:Name="SettingsStartWithWindowsBtn"
                                BorderThickness="10"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.Column="4"
                                Width="40"
                                Height="40"
                                Content="{DynamicResource off}"
                                FontSize="18"
                                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Focusable="False"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                IsEnabled="True"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                BorderBrush="White"
                                Foreground="Red"
                                Click="SettingsButtons_Click"
                                Style="{DynamicResource RoundedCheckboxStyle}"/>
```

and I have this XAML code to make a `ComboBox` control at line 818:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="SettingsLanguageSelection"
                                  BorderThickness="10"
                                  Grid.Column="4"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Width="100"
                                  Height="30"
                                  FontSize="16"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  IsTabStop="False"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  BorderBrush="White"
                                  Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}">

                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="SettingsLanguageEnglish"
                                          Content="{DynamicResource english}"
                                          FontSize="15"
                                          Focusable="False"
                                          IsSelected="True"
                                          Selected="SettingsLanguageEnglish_Selected"/>

                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="SettingsLanguageRomanian"
                                          Content="{DynamicResource romanian}"
                                          Focusable="False"
                                          FontSize="15" Selected="SettingsLanguageRomanian_Selected"/>

                        </ComboBox>
```

The `Selected` events go to a C# method that references the `SettingsStartWithWindowsBtn` button, which of course is null because it's created after the `ComboBox` control.

Now I don't know how to create the button before the `ComboBox` control if the button is in another parent in the XAML code.